# Request to undelete answer that has been edited into correctness

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-answer

[Science Fiction Short Story about Computer controlled Utopia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122030/science-fiction-short-story-about-computer-controlled-utopia)

The author wrote a follow-up that was actually a modification to their question, and it was deleted. They have since added the answer, but a moderator deleted it, so I cannot vote to undelete.

Comment: Surely you can flag for moderator attention?

Comment: Boy is my face red... flagged.

Comment: It must be a day for this... flagged the following too: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153839/story-identification-bless-the-beasts-that-bless-us/159983#159983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before seeing this meta post, I'd already seen your flag, **undeleted the answer, and edited it to be more clearly an answer**: putting the name of the story clearly at the top and removing some of the now-obsolete "I'm looking for this story too ... I read it around this year ..." text.

Comment: Can you also get https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153839/story-identification-bless-the-beasts-that-bless-us/159983#159983?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots [meta-tag:status-completed] (that answer might still need some improvement, but you're the man for that :-) )

Comment: ^_^ Everyone has their niches. Although, honestly, this one doesn't have much knowledge online that I can find, and my library doesn't have it, so I'm requesting a copy via ILL.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the only answer was initially a "I have this problem too", which was edited *by the answerer* to tell that *they* had found an answer to *their* question. While that may be the answer to the original question as well, that is not how it's currently presented.

So I see no reason to undelete that answer.

The best solution would be for the answerer to edit their answer into a proper answer, or for us to do so.

Comment: Answers can be edited while deleted, but they can't be commented on (except by mods). I don't see why "it includes a possible answer, but isn't presented very well" is a reason not to undelete. Why not just edit the answer into a more presentable form and then undelete? (I've now done this.)